# Is there an idioms for "nothing is yet clear"

Tags: idioms, proverbs

I usually say that something is not clear yet like "it is still in the wind" **when something is uncertain**.

Is there any English **idiom** or proverb that describe this saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression [***up in the air***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up-in-the-air) is a good example.

Depending on context, an alternative could be:

**At a crossroads**

From Vocabulary.com:

> [**crossroads**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/crossroads) (*n.*) a point in time when a critical decision must be made

For example:

*We are at a crossroads and don't know which path to take as the potential results are uncertain.*